# Can I use multiple labels for a form element?

Tags: html, forms

Would the following be a valid usage of the label element in HTML5?

```
<label for="select">Some text</label>
<select id="select">
   ...
</select>
<label for="select">...more text</label>
```

The [HTML5 specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-label-element) don't seem to have anything to say about it.

edit: This question is now old. In the current wording it is clear that one element can have multiple labels (but not the other way around):

> Labelable elements have a NodeList object associated with them that represents the list of label elements, in tree order, whose labeled control is the element in question.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can have multiple labels that point to the same form control and it's legal.

According to [HTML 4 Documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.9.1):

> The LABEL element may be used to attach information to controls. Each LABEL element is associated with exactly one form control.
>
> The for attribute associates a label with another control explicitly: the value of the for attribute must be the same as the value of the id attribute of the associated control element. **More than one LABEL may be associated with the same control by creating multiple references via the for attribute.**

Comment: Guess that's as close as we get, even though I still can figure it out from the HTML5 spec

Comment: I might add that in the current wording of the [html5 spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-label-element) it's implied that one element can have multiple labels (but not the other way around).

Answer (score 1):

I just tested whether current screen reader / browser combinations will behave as expected, meaning: they associate all existing labels with the input and announce them all when focusing the input. This is useful especially when tabbing through form inputs with Windows desktop screen readers.

```html
<label for="name">Your name:</label>
<input id="name" />
<label for="name">If forgotten, please consult your birth certificate.
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/jmuheim/pen/OJvxzVG

- NVDA+Chrome: Works ✅
- NVDA+FF: Works ✅
- JAWS+Chrome: Works ✅
- JAWS+FF: Works ✅

Note: mobile screen readers not tested, as they do not offer tabbing, which renders the above irrelevant.