# Multiple label elements for form inputs: how important is their sequence for accessibility?

Tags: forms, input, label, accessibility, sequence

I want to create a complex form. Besides `<fieldset>`/`<legend>` to group several input fields, in addition to the general `<label>`, many inputs have a descriptive text.

```html
<label for="name">Name</label>
<input id="name" />
<label for="name">If forgotten, please consult your birth certificate.</label>
```

Due to simplicity, we decided to use multiple `<label>`s instead of `aria-describedby`, because the latter needs additional unique IDs in the code, which is a hassle.

Side note: Some years ago, using multiple `<label>`s would have been a no-go, because some screen reader would refuse to read all of them. It seems that this problem is now resolved: [Can I use multiple labels for a form element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24204063/can-i-use-multiple-labels-for-a-form-element/73167296#answer-73167296)

Now I wonder how important the sequence of the `<label>`s is. All tested screen readers use the sequence in the DOM, which I feel is correct. Alas, the code above will be conveyed like this:

> Name
> If forgotten, please consult your birth certificate.
> Text input

But what if (for design reasons) I need to interchange the two labels?

```html
<label for="name">If forgotten, please consult your birth certificate.</label>
<input id="name" />
<label for="name">Name</label>
```

> If forgotten, please consult your birth certificate.
> Name
> Text input

From a strict WCAG point of view, I feel that both versions are 100% valid, even though the first one might feel a bit more intuitive. Or am I wrong? Could anybody complain about this situation? In my opinion, this would be complaining on a very "high level" (i.e. not very substantial).

In the end, we could still use `aria-describedby`, but it's just ugly to code:

```html
<p id="name-description">If forgotten, please consult your birth certificate.</p><!-- Needs an ID -->
<input id="name" aria-describedby="name-description" /><!-- Needs to reference that ID -->
<label for="name">Name</label>
```

Even though I'm an accessibility ambassador, I don't think we should punish web developers too much with all that nitty-gritty `aria` stuff and let them choose solutions that are both simple and effective.

I'm happy to hear your thoughts.

Comment: sorry to put it that way, but if placing unique IDs in your components is a hassle, your setup needs adjustment.
Otherwise, you could also simply wrap all texts inside a single `<label>` element together with the input. No need for IDs.
And if you need to do something for design reasons, you should simply not do it in the DOM, but in CSS, see separation of concerns.

Comment: Coders are paid to code. Whether it's a hassle is (mostly) irrelevant, so I'm with @Andy on this. I'm a coder myself and I'll write things that will be best for the **user**, not for me. From a high level perspective, the "birth certificate" label is more of an instruction (WCAG 3.3.2) and not really the field's label. It's a best practice to associate instructions via `aria-describedby`. Note that in ARIA 1.3 (release date?), a new `aria-description` will be added that is similar to `aria-label` in that it can be a string instead of an ID, https://w3c.github.io/aria/#aria-description

Comment: I don't see well why you want to use two labels instead of aria-describedby and why the former would be easier to code than the later. If you still need to use two labels, I don't see either why you couldn't make sure that they appear in the correct order in the DOM and fix their visual placement in CSS.

Comment: It isn't a big deal if the labels are spoken in the wrong order in your example, but it makes you navigating slower. Imagine if you have 20 fields like that and if, each time, the description / side note is read before the actual label. You will take more time finding the particular field you want to edit and you are much greater chances to miss it if you are repeatedly pressing F/Shift+F or Tab/Shift+Tab too fast. Additionally it can quickly become annoying to hear the description each time, especially if it's long.